# pyfpdf write_html In-line CSS style attribute not working in fpdf python

Tags: python, html, css, django, fpdf

I am trying to create a PDF file by using pyfpdf in python Django. the following code snippet I am trying to generate the pdf of HTML code and I am using the in-line CSS, but it not rendering the css style

```
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin
import os

class WriteHtmlPDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass

pdf = WriteHtmlPDF()
# First page
pdf.add_page()

html = f"""<h3>xxxxx</h3>
 <div style="border:1px solid #000">
     <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
         <tr><th width=20 align="left">xxxxxxxx:</th><td width="100">xxxxxxxx</td></tr>
         <tr><th width=20 align="left">xxxxxxxx:</th><td width="100">xxxxxxxxx</td></tr>
         <tr><th width=20 align="left">xxxxxxxx:</th><td width="100">xxxxxxxxx</td></tr>
         <tr><th width=20 align="left">xxxxxxxx:</th><td width="100">xxxxxxxxx</td></tr>
     </table>
 </div>
 <div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px;">
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td width="20">xxxxxx: 1</td>
             <td width="20">xxxxxx: 0</td>
             <td width="20">xxxxxx: 1</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </div>"""
```

PDF file get generated but without the CSS styling.

Answer (score 2):

https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/write_html/index.html#details

inline css is not supported in pyfpdf